# Fonts and font size in HTML textboxes

Tags: html

Imagine that I have a *textarea* in HTML. The code would look something like this:

```html
<textarea rows="4" cols="100" id="i" CLASS="A"></textarea>
```

How can I change the font and font size? And is it possible to have multiple different font sizes and fonts in there?

Comment: You change them with the style attribute.

Comment: Embed a span element and style it.

Comment: if you use CSS then define CLASS "A"

Answer (score 1):

You can style the `textarea` just like any other element with CSS. Whether you want to do it in an external stylesheet, internal stylesheet, or with inline style is up to you.

As for your second question, I'm not sure what your use case is, but it is not possible with HTML or CSS alone. You'll need JavaScript.

```css
div {
  font-family: serif;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: blue;
}

.textbox {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 3rem;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>i'm a div</div>
<textarea class='textbox' rows="4" cols="100" id="i" CLASS="A">i'm a textarea</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easyest way is to do this with the `style` attribute

```html
<textarea rows="4" cols="100" id="i" CLASS="A" style="font-size:30px;font-family:courier"></textarea>
```